# Analogue of Fermat's little theorem for Bernoulli numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, divisors-multiples, conjectures, bernoulli-numbers

Is the following analogue of Fermat's Little Theorem for Bernoulli numbers true?

> Let $D_{2n}$ be the denominator of $\frac{B_{2n}}{4n}$ where $B_n$ is
> the $n$-th [Bernoulli number](http://oeis.org/A006863). If $\gcd(a, D_{2n}) = 1$ then
>
> $$ a^{2n} \equiv 1\pmod{D_{2n}}.$$

This question was [posted in MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4343529/conjectured-analogue-of-fermats-little-theorem-for-bernouli-numbers) 3 weeks back but it is still open. Hence posting in MO.

Comment: For the denominator of $B_{2n}$ itself this follows immediately from https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Staudt%E2%80%93Clausen_theorem

Comment: I think this is true, see the comment by Peter J. Cameron to the OEIS entry [A006863](https://oeis.org/A006863). This comment implies that $2n$ is a multiple of the [exponent](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Exponent_of_a_group) of the group of units of $D_{2n}$, which immediately implies the statement in your question.

Comment: Also this follows from the comment by T. Khovanova: "Michael Lugo (see link) conjectures, and Peter McNamara proves, that a(n) = gcd_{ primes p > 2n+1 } (p^(2n) - 1)." (take a prime congruent to $a$ modulo $D_n$)

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A proof is essentially given in Section 5.1 of [Notes on primitive lambda-roots](http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/%7Epjc/csgnotes/lambda.pdf) by P. J. Cameron and D. A. Preece.